# SNMP Manager - Multiple IP address -issue

Tags: esp32, tcpip

I have multiple SNMP devices on the same network and I am trying to request, *via OID numbers*, each SNMP device and assign the **response** into an array.
When I request a single IP, I get the correct response as expected.

**Problem:**
If I run the same code in a for loop (*multiple ip's 192.168.1.150, 192.168.1.151, etc*), I get duplicate info.
*I might be using the wrong callback method, or the SNMP Manager can not dynamically change the ip address..*
I have researched a lot of topics and tried many avenues, but I can't get past this point.

**If anyone can assist me, it would help a lot!!**

---

**Example Output:**
*The model name and serial should be different on each ip*

```
----------------------
192.168.8.150
KONICA MINOLTA bizhub C658
A79J021002278
----------------------
192.168.8.151
KONICA MINOLTA bizhub C658
A79J021002278
----------------------
192.168.8.152
KONICA MINOLTA bizhub C658
A79J021002278
----------------------
192.168.8.153
KONICA MINOLTA bizhub C658
A79J021002278
----------------------
192.168.8.154
KONICA MINOLTA bizhub C658
A79J021002278
```

**Here is the code**

```
#if defined(ESP8266)
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> // ESP8266 Core WiFi Library         
#else
#include <WiFi.h>        // ESP32 Core WiFi Library    
#endif

#include <string.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <Arduino_SNMP_Manager.h>

//************************************
//* Your WiFi info                   *
//************************************
const char *ssid = "Workmin_Sales";
const char *password = "workmin92429242";
//************************************

//************************************
//* SNMP Device Info                 *
//************************************
const char *community = "public";
const int snmpVersion = 1; // SNMP Version 1 = 0, SNMP Version 2 = 1
// OIDs
const char *oidModelName = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1";               // OctetString SysName
const char *oidSerialNumber = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.17.1";              // OctetString SysName
//************************************

//************************************
//* Settings                         *
//************************************
int pollInterval = 20000; // delay in milliseconds
//************************************

//************************************
//* Initialise                       *
//************************************
// Variables 
char *modelNameArray[5];
char *serialNumberArray[5];

char modelName[50];
char *modelNameResponse = modelName;
char serialNumber[50];
char *serialNumberResponse = serialNumber;

// Blank callback pointer for each OID
ValueCallback *callbackSerialNumber;
ValueCallback *callbackModelName;
//************************************

unsigned long pollStart = 0;
// SNMP Objects
WiFiUDP udp;                                           // UDP object used to send and receive packets
SNMPManager snmp = SNMPManager(community);             // Starts an SMMPManager to listen to replies to get-requests
SNMPGet snmpRequest = SNMPGet(community, snmpVersion); // Starts an SMMPGet instance to send requests


//************************************
//* Function declarations            *
//************************************
void getSNMP();
//************************************

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");
  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  snmp.setUDP(&udp); // give snmp a pointer to the UDP object
  snmp.begin();      // start the SNMP Manager
}

void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  snmp.loop();
  if (millis() - pollStart >= pollInterval)
  {
    pollStart += pollInterval; // this prevents drift in the delays
    
    getSNMP();
    // doSNMPCalculations(); // Do something with the data collected
  }
}

void getSNMP()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Build a SNMP get-request add each OID to the request
    IPAddress router(192, 168, 8, i + 150);

    // Get callbacks from creating a handler for each of the OID
    callbackSerialNumber = snmp.addStringHandler(router, oidSerialNumber, &serialNumberResponse);
    callbackModelName = snmp.addStringHandler(router, oidModelName, &modelNameResponse);

    snmpRequest.addOIDPointer(callbackSerialNumber);
    snmpRequest.addOIDPointer(callbackModelName);


    snmpRequest.setIP(WiFi.localIP()); // IP of the listening MCU
    // snmpRequest.setPort(501);  // Default is UDP port 161 for SNMP. But can be overriden if necessary.
    snmpRequest.setUDP(&udp);
    snmpRequest.setRequestID(rand() % 5555);
    snmpRequest.sendTo(router);
    snmpRequest.clearOIDList();
    delay(1000);

    modelNameArray[i] = modelNameResponse;
    serialNumberArray[i] = serialNumberResponse;
    Serial.print("192.168.8.");
    Serial.println(i + 150);
    Serial.println(modelNameArray[i]);
    Serial.println(serialNumberArray[i]);
    Serial.println("----------------------");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see multiple issues with the example above.

1. The `snmpRequest.sendTo(router);` will send the SNMP packet out. But you need to call `snmp.loop()` to read the incoming replies to your request. So you need to restructure the code so that you can call loop() potentially many times in order to wait for the incoming replies before you read and store the values.
2. `serialNumberResponse` is a pointer to a character array `serialNumber` (likewise for the model). If the callback returned serial number `123ABC` the first time, and the next device was called `1XD` then the array would have a value of `1XDABC`. So if you plan to re-use the variable, you'll need to clear it between uses something like: `memset(serialNumber, 0, sizeof(serialNumber));`
3. As you might not always get a successful response, or a response within the time allowed, the value may be still blank, if you're looking to store the values in another variable, you may want to ensure they aren't empty, as this would overwrite the value you may have had back on a previously successful call. If you were dealing with numbers, the value might also be that of a previous call. As pointed out in the answer above, you're dealing with pointers, so if you want to store the value you need to copy the value out, otherwise, you'll just point to the same pointer.

I hope this helps point you in the right direction. I've added an example to the library to show how multiple devices can be queried and the results stored in an array, see: https://github.com/shortbloke/Arduino_SNMP_Manager/tree/master/examples/ESP_Multiple_SNMP_Device_Polling. It stores the responses directly into the array. This might cause values to be cleared in the event of a timeout, I've not tested it completely.

Martin

Comment: Thank you so much, Martin. I tried the example and it is working seamlessly! When I get money, I am gonna buy you a few beers :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not storing the data in your array, you're storing a pointer to the storage where the callback stores its data. So every entry gets the same pointer to the same storage, which gets its content changed. So all the array entries see the same (last) content.

It took me many years to properly get my head around C pointers.

Instead of just assigning (`=`) the value you need to *copy the content*.

Since you just have an array of pointers that can be done with `strdup()` which allocates a new block of RAM and copies the contents to it. Be sure to use `free()` on that allocated block when you've finished with it.

- [strdup](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)